# Subtitles on Apple TV does not show up on Auto mode

Tags: avplayer, tvos, apple-tv, subtitle, m3u8

When I select the Auto(Recommended) mode on AppleTV, subtitles do not show up. I need to select the language to show it. The m3u8 file has the following -

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs",NAME="Arabic",LANGUAGE="ar",URI="ccs/ara/sub_6693585_index.m3u8" 
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs",NAME="English",DEFAULT=YES,AUTOSELECT=YES,LANGUAGE="eng",URI="ccs/eng/sub_6693585_index.m3u8"
```

What am I doing wrong here? Please suggest.

Comment: @MihribanMinaz, I did not understand that. Could you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

My playlist looks like this:

```
ID="subs",NAME="Arabic",FORCED=NO,AUTOSELECT=YES,URI="/link.m3u8",LANGUAGE="ara"
```

maybe this element would help you `FORCED=NO`